# Can't Upgrade mysql 8.0.32 to mysql 8.0.33 on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, mysql

1.I try to run sudo apt upgrade and also dist upgrade, still cannot upgrade, the package still kept back.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
 mysql-community-client : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installable
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

2.I read it from ask ubuntu the solutions is to purge and remove mysql-community-client and i get the second error like i paste below, please help.i can't remove or purge mysql-community-client [MySQL - Cannot update to 8.0.31 from 8.0.30 at Ubuntu 22.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440198/mysql-cannot-update-to-8-0-31-from-8-0-30-at-ubuntu-22-04-1)

3. How can i fix this without losing all mysql database?

   ```
    sudo apt purge mysql-community-client
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     dbconfig-mysql : Depends: default-mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or
                               virtual-mysql-client
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
   ```

Comment: We've had this situation before but I can't find the question. Remove `mysql-community-client`, install `mysql-client` and you'll be fine.

Comment: i post this because i can't remove mysql-community-client, when i try that command it give me The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbconfig-mysql : Depends: default-mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or
                           virtual-mysql-client
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: Also remove `mysql-common`, `mysql-server-8.0` and `dbconfig-mysql` before retrying. Do not purge the server (it may remove your data, I'm not sure).

Comment: @Jos thanks alot it's working and my database is safe, appreciate your time and guidance.